# Different Output in Visual Studio 2012 and c++11

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, gcc, c++11

The Following code produces different output in Visual Studio 2012 and c++11.

Problem:

http://www.codechef.com/FEB14/problems/SUBMIN

Little Elephant is playing a game with arrays. He is given an array A0, A1, ..., AN−1 of N integers. And then Q queries are given, each containing an integer K. He has to tell how many subarrays satisfy the condition: the function foo returns K when it is applied to the subarray.

In this problem, a subarray is defined as a sequence of continuous elements Ai, Ai+1, ..., Aj where 0 ≤ i ≤ j ≤ N−1. The function foo, when applied to an array, returns the minimum of all the elements in the array.

For example, foo returns 5 when it is applied to the array [7, 5, 10, 7, 5, 8]. Please note that the subarrays Ai, Ai+1, ..., Aj and Ak, Ak+1, ..., Al are different if and only if i ≠ k or j ≠ l in this problem.

Input

The first line of input contains N, denoting the size of the array. The next line contains N space separated integers A0, A1, ..., AN−1, denoting the array. Then the next line contains Q, denoting the number of queries. Each query consists of one integer per line, denoting K.

Output

For each query, print the required number of subarrays.

Input:

> 5
>
> 4 1 2 3 4
>
> 4
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 6

1

Output in VS2012 and gcc 4.3.2 is

```
2
2
0
8
```

While the output in gcc 4.8.1 and c++11 is:

```
2
2
0
24
```

http://ideone.com/DUp72c

http://ideone.com/kFTlNe

Code:

```
int main() {

    map <int, vector<int> >b;
    int  arr[51], n;
    int ans = 0;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
         cin >> arr[i];
         b[arr[i]].push_back(i);
    }
    int q, query, pos, l1, l2, vlength;
    cin >> q;
    while (q--)
    {
        ans = 0, l1 = 0, l2 = 0;
        cin >> query;
        vlength = b[query].size();
        int t = 0, c = 0;
        while (t < vlength){
            c = 1;
            for (size_t i = b[query].at(t) + 1; (i<n) && (arr[i] >= query); i++)
                if (arr[i] == query)
                {
                    c++;
                }

            for (size_t i = 0; i < c; i++)
            {
                l2 = 0;
                for (size_t k = b[query].at(t + i) - 1; (k >= 0) && (arr[k] > query); k--)
                    l2++;


                for (size_t j = i; j < c; j++)
                {
                    l1 = 0;
                    for (size_t m = b[query].at(t + j) + 1; (m<n) && (arr[m] > query); m++)
                        l1++;

                    ans += (l1 + 1)*(l2 + 1);
                }
            }
            t += c;

        }

        cout << ans << endl;


    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what this code is supposed to do? This is just a code dump.

Comment: Well, this was my response to a question on codechef.
http://www.codechef.com/FEB14/problems/SUBMIN

Comment: If you are downvoting, Please mention the reason in comments.This is not intended to solve any problem . Solution to it has already been submitted in gcc 4.3.2

Comment: -1. Entirely without use or context. (0) There's no mention of the supplied input, just the output. (1) No description of the purpose of the code. If the off-site link provides that, then re-visit it and copy that description to here. (2) Is there even a question here? If so, what?

Comment: I have now provided as much knowledge to the question as possible.
Still, the problem to be solved is secondary.
What the question was about was difference in behaviour for which i wanted an explanation.
Please comment if any other edits are required.

Comment: I think he is asking why there is different output for same code and input as shown by
http://ideone.com/DUp72c
http://ideone.com/kFTlNe

Comment: You use DIFFERENT code for the two ideone tests. Diff it, find the discrepancy, stop at that line with a debugger, print the variables, think.

Comment: Its the same code.I am sorry you might have seen when i was trying to edit it.

Comment: **Now** it is the same code. When I downloaded it it was different. [This](http://ideone.com/wX1vPx) is the version that was different, and it gives the same result on vc2012, vc2010, gcc4.3.2, gcc4.8.1, with or without c++11. Yes the problem is in that one difference.

Comment: The problem has been solved, Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to subscript out of range. Double check by changing

```
int arr[51];
```

to

```
array<int, 51> arr;
```

You should get the assertion error. I suspect different output is a result of different compiler behavior on handling array index out of bound, in one of the case assigning arr[i] where i>50 is changing value of some other variable.

Comment: Just changing to `std::array` is not enough. He would also have to use the `at()` member function to get bounds checking.

Comment: Yes, the answer is as you describe.
Actually in line 38 it was caused when k was -1.
Since k is size_t, it assigned some large value to k.
Here, the problem has been resolved:
http://ideone.com/ZcpdWH